# Error No module call named “networking” is declared in security. - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-aws-modules

I am getting an error :
Error: Reference to undeclared module

on modules\security\security.tf line 6, in resource “aws_security_group” “Web-sg”:
6: vpc_id = module.networking.vpcid

No module call named “networking” is declared in security.

```
This is directory structure that I am following currently,
│ main.tf
│ provider.tf
│ terraform.tfstate
│ terraform.tfstate.backup
│ variables.tf
│
└───modules
├───networking
│ networking.tf
│ outputs.tf
│ variables.tf
│
└───security
security.tf
variables.tf
```

My main.tf

```
    module "networking" {
    source = "./modules/networking"
   }
    module "security" {
    source = "./modules/security"

}
```

I created a module named networking where I created all network resources:

```
    resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = var.cidr_block
    
    tags = {
        Name = var.vpc_name
    }
    }
#Creating Public Subnets
  resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  cidr_block = element(var.subnet_cidr_public,count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.azs,count.index)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.map_public_ip_on_launch

  tags =  {
      Name = "Subnet-Public-${element(var.subnet_cidr_public,count.index)}"
  }    
  }


# Creating and Associating to the VPC the Internet Gateway

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "IGW-VPC" {
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id 

   tags = {
     Name = var.igw-name
   }

}

# Creating Route Table - Public
# Creating Public Route Table 

resource "aws_route_table" "public-route" { 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  
  route { 
    cidr_block = var.cidr_block_route 
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.IGW-VPC.id 
  }

    tags = {
      Name = var.public_route_name
    }
    
}

# Associating Subnet Public-1a to the Public Route Table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "association-public1a" {
  subnet_id = var.subnet_public_1a
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public-route.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "association-public1b" {
  subnet_id = var.subnet_public_1b
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public-route.id
}
```

I created a module named security where I created all security groups:

What I am doing wrong ? How can I fix it ?

```
resource "aws_security_group" "Web-sg" {
  name = var.web-sg_name
  description = var.web-sg_description
  vpc_id = module.networking.vpcid
  ingress { 
    description = var.description22
    from_port = var.port22
    to_port  = var.port22
    protocol = var.protocol 
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr000
  }
  ingress { 
    description =  var.description80 
    from_port = var.port80
    to_port  = var.port80
    protocol = var.protocol 
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr000 
  }
  ingress { 
    description = var.description443
    from_port = var.port443
    to_port  = var.port443
    protocol = var.protocol 
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr000 
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = var.port0 
    to_port     = var.port0 
    protocol    = var.protocol0
    cidr_blocks = var.cidr000 
  }
  tags = {
    "Name" = var.web-sg_name
  }
}
```

As you can see I created in the resource "aws_security_group" "Web-sg" {
vpc_id = module.networking.vpcid

and an outputs.tf file

```
output "vpcid" {
    value = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}
```

But I am getting this error

What I am doing wrong ? How can I fix it ?
Thanks
Marcus

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare modules as follows in ./main.tf:

```
module "networking" {
  source = "./modules/networking"
}

module "security" {
  source = "./modules/security"
}
```

The references to **module.networking** and **module.security** are only in scope for local variables, resources, data sources, outputs, and expressions in TF files in the same directory (./*.tf in this case).

Since ./modules/security/security.tf is notin the same directory as ./main.tf, it cannot make reference to module.networking as you are trying here.

A simple fix is to supply **vpcid** as an input variable to the security module and get its value from **module.networking.vpcid**:

```
module "networking" {
  source = "./modules/networking"
}

module "security" {
  source = "./modules/security"
  vpcid = module.networking.vpcid
}
```

For this to work you need to modify ./modules/security/variables.tf to declare **vpcid** as an input variable:

```
variable "vpcid" {
  description = "ID of the VPC in which security resources are deployed"
  type = string
}
```

And change the reference in ./modules/security/security.tf:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "Web-sg" {
  // ...
  vpc_id = var.vpcid
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alain !! I've tested here and It is working !!!

Comment: You can also reference modules called from git or other registries using URL in the source. e.g.: `source = "git@github.com:xx/tf-aws-supercluster?ref=v1.3.4"`